# Get country code for timezone using pytz?

Tags: python, pytz

I'm using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#country-information). I've read through the entire documentation sheet, but didn't see how this could be done.

I have a timezone: America/Chicago. All I want is to get the respective country code for this timezone: US.

It shows that I can do the opposite, such as:

```
>>> country_timezones('ch')
['Europe/Zurich']
>>> country_timezones('CH')
['Europe/Zurich']
```

but I need to do it the other way around.

Can this be done in Python, using pytz (or any other way for that matter)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `country_timezones` object from `pytz` and generate an inverse mapping:

```
from pytz import country_timezones

timezone_country = {}
for countrycode in country_timezones:
    timezones = country_timezones[countrycode]
    for timezone in timezones:
        timezone_country[timezone] = countrycode
```

Now just use the resulting dictionary:

```
>>> timezone_country['Europe/Zurich']
u'CH'
```

Comment: it would break if the same timezone name is used in different countries. There are no such names in `country_timezones`. But some common timezones are not in it e.g., UTC, US/Central, US/Eastern, Canada/Central, etc

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian what did you mean by your last sentence? Those timezones are not in what?

Comment: All timezones defined in `pytz` map to exactly one country. Thus, it doesn't break.

Comment: @mohabitar: those timezones are not in `country_timezones` values therefore `timezone_country` that is generated using `country_timezones` will produce KeyError for UTC, US/Central, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem here. He didn't ask to include general purpose timezones like `UTC` into the mapping.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thats odd, why are those timezones not included? Arent they common enough?

Comment: @mohabitar: they are not included, because the don't exist in `pytz.country_timezones`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian so should I check `if 'Europe/Zurich' in timezone_country` before accessing the value?

Comment: @mohabitar: if you use timezones that are not in `country_timezones` values then yes, such timezones require other solution

Answer (score 6):

This is easy. You have a `dict` mapping each country to a list of timezones. You want to map each `list` member back to the `dict`.

Rather than just give the answer, let's see how to get it.

First, if you just had a `dict` mapping each country to a single timezone, this would be a simple reverse mapping:

```
timezone_countries = {timezone: country 
                      for country, timezone in country_timezones.iteritems()}
```

But this won't work; you have a mapping to a list of timezones, and you want each timezone in that list to map back to the country. That English description "each timezone in that list" is trivially translatable to Python:

```
timezone_countries = {timezone: country 
                      for country, timezones in country_timezones.iteritems()
                      for timezone in timezones}
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> from pytz import country_timezones
>>> timezone_countries = {timezone: country 
                          for country, timezones in country_timezones.iteritems()
                          for timezone in timezones}
>>> timezone_countries['Europe/Zurich']
u'CH'
```

Side note: You didn't mention Python 2 vs. 3, so I assumed 2. If you're on 3, change `iteritems` to `items`, and the output will be `'CH'` instead of `u'CH'`.