# How to get UTC from timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get UTC from timezone with python?

Timezone: `Asia/Pontianak`

From timezone (Asia/Pontianak), will resulted `+7`, `+8` or something like that.

Comment: You should try to give an example of your input and how you want the output to be. It helps in getting answers quickly.

Comment: But I think this is what you want : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020690/get-country-code-for-timezone-using-pytz)

Comment: But i want the result is a number.

Comment: Like this https://greenwichmeantime.com/time/indonesia/

Comment: Asia/Pontianak : +7

Comment: you could try to map all the regions to the UTC code. as there arnt that many.

Comment: Can't it automatically?

Comment: I've seen a lot of data here: `https://www.countries-of the-world.com/world-time-zones.html`

Comment: Yes u could extract them all from that site. Try scraping it it you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with timezones in python there is a need to use the `pytz` Python library.

**The first step is to install `pytz` because it is not a standard library:**

`pip install pytz`

**OR:**

`pip3 install pytz`

**Then here is the code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

UTC = pytz.utc #storing the UTC property for later

time_zone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Pontianak') #get the local timzone for later

local_date_time = datetime.now(time_zone) #Formating the time to Asia/Pontianak
print(local_date_time)
#2021-01-08 18:57:02.691163+07:00

# ...and to UTC:
date_time_utc = local_date_time.astimezone(UTC)
print(date_time_utc)
#2021-01-08 18:57:02.691163+07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone
get_time = pytz.timezone('Asia/Pontianak').localize(datetime.now())
print(get_time)
```

Output

> 2021-01-08 17:41:34.686607+07:00

Now, to get the Timezone result

```
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
print(now_utc)
```